# How can I use Spread Sheets API as a batch program?

Tags: java, batch-file, authentication, google-api, google-sheets

I made a batch program which get some spread sheets and update them with Client Login method.
It had moved until 26 May.
But, it is no longer work now because authentication error happen.

I want to execute a batch program for SpreadSheets using the cron.
So, I tried to read the below pages and to migrate to OAuth2.0 method.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/client-login
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize

However, I couldn't understand how I use OAuth2.0 as a batch in Java code. 
What I want to know is an authentication way that it doesn't need to operate manually when Spread Sheets API is run.

Please tell me a solution of this problem.

Thank you.

```
// current java source code
public static SpreadsheetService getService() {
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration");
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    // get Username and Password from JSON file
    String username = getValueJsonFile("Username", JSON_FILE);
    String password = getValueJsonFile("Password", JSON_FILE);

    try {
        service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error code: " + e.getCodeName());
        log.error(getMessage("WRONG_USER_PASS"));
    }
    return service;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, what I want to know is an authentication way that it doesn't need to manual operation when Spread Sheets API is run.